# cakephp Trying to update a MySQL record where record id already exists

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, model

I am saving multiple records for a model and I want to update existing records if a company_id already exists.

I am using this code in the Model:

```
function beforeSave() {

        $found = $this->find("first",array(
                "recursive" => -1,
                "conditions" => array("company_id" => $this->data['Osm']['company_id'])));
        if(isset($found))
        {
            $this->data['Osm']['id'] = $found['Osm']['id'];
        }
        return true;
    }
```

but I am getting the following error: **Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '60' for key 'PRIMARY'**

I understand why I am getting this error but I can't seem to force an update rather than an insert.

Comment: Looks like a logic error... you're trying to change the record ID before it's saved? If you find another record you can't just use it's ID... Try to search for this record BEFORE running the save() method

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `$id` member variable on the method instead of in the data. Do `$this->id = $found['Osm']['id'];` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice Joeb, I tried that but the record are still being duplicated.

Comment: if(isset($found))
  {
   $this->id = $found['Osm']['id'];
   echo $this->id;exit();
  }                                                               The echo statement is showing the correct id....